# Rails: No Method Error (undefined method `create')

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've setup oauth in my rails app using Doorkeeper. I'm able to login and retrieve the access token from my client iOS app. When I try to post data I'm getting a no method error.

This is my API code:

```
module Api
module V1
    class RolesController < ActionController::Base
    doorkeeper_for :all
    respond_to :json

    def create
        respond_with current_user.create(ob_params)
    end

    def index
        respond_with current_user
    end

def ob_params
  params.require(:role).permit(:submit_by, :gender, :short_desc, :long_desc, :title)
end

private

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= Boss.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
    end

    end
end
end
```

The logs show this:

```
      [1m[35mBoss Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "bosses".* FROM "bosses" WHERE "bosses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for #<Boss:0x007fe1d037a410>):
  app/controllers/api/v1/roles_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not following your logic. You can't create something that already exists, which current_user it looks like does. I would expect:

```
def create
    respond_with Boss.create(ob_params)
end
```

and/or

```
def update
    respond_with current_user.update(ob_params)
end
```

Edit. What about:

```
def create
    @role = Role.create(ob_params)
    current_user.roles << @role
    @role.save #Needed?
    current_user.save #Needed?
    respond_with @role
end
```

Comment: Ah, you helped me see where I went wrong. It should have been: Role.create(ob_params)